# SSIS CDC Control Task Mark Initial Load - db_owner / sys_admin permission required on source database?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, cdc

Context is that I'm trying to perform an initial load of data into our database and then use CDC to incrementally modify said data so that we don't need to run a massive import each night. Is there a way to achieve this without running into the issue described below?

I set my SSIS package up to do:

1. Mark Initial Load Start
2. Data Flow Task
3. Mark Initial Load End

The Mark Initial Load Start is failing due to the user not being db_owner or a sysadmin:

```
Information: 0x4002F304 at Mark Initial Load Start, CDC Control Task: "State value read from the state table [dbo].[cdc_states] with state name CDC_State is ''.".
Error: 0x4002F304 at Mark Initial Load Start, CDC Control Task: "Only members of the sysadmin fixed server role or db_owner fixed database role can perform this operation. Contact an administrator with sufficient permissions to perform this operation.".
Task failed: Mark Initial Load Start
```

The error isn't clear whether this issue is on the source or sink side. I'm assuming it's on the source side... The problem is that the source side limited permissions and I will not be able to get db_owner or sysadmin. CDC has already been enabled on the database and on all the tables for me.

I'm trying to understand if the db_owner or sysadmin role is actually necessary here as-per the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/cdc-control-task?view=sql-server-ver15). Maybe I'm going about this all wrong in general?

Comment: As you noted, this is in accordance with the documentation for the integration services "CDC Control Task". I don't know what TSQL that task is actually executing, but you don't actually need db_owner or sysadmin to just "use" CDC. When you set up a table using `sp_cdc_enable_table` you can define a role, and then add members to that role. Whether doing that and using a member of that role to execute the package will work for this particular task built into SSIS, I don't know. If you do try this approach, you should also give the same user select permission on the underlying tables.

Comment: If you are executing this via SQL Agent, you could also set up your connection strings in SSIS to use integrated security, set up an agent proxy account which is a member of the db_owner role, and execute the package using that proxy account.

Comment: @allmhuran Neither do I which is the most frustrating part, I'm requesting logs from the party that manages the source DB to see what SQL is being run that fails.

The user has SELECT on all the tables, and I'm able to manually run the CDC functions that get created for each capture instance.

Comment: One thing I did notice was in this security considerations note: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/cdc-flow-components?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver16#access-to-cdc-database-current-lsn

They mention the need to be able to run sp_replincrementlsn

Comment: I have personally never used the MS baked SSIS CDC tasks, but our EDW team ultimately chose to use Task Factory extensions, so I assume they are less than stellar (while the data flow pipeline of SSIS is fantastically performant, the actual IDE and tasks provided by MS themselves are, on the whole, awful). You can of course also "roll your own logic" to use CDC, which is what I personally have always done, and in which case you would never use `sp_replincrementlsn`, but rather the CDC provided `fn_cdc_get_max_lsn` function.